# How to center the hint in a WP8 Toolkit PhoneTextBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm using a WP8 toolkit PhoneTextBox control. I'd like the hint to be centered, vertically and horizontally. The following code got the vertical part, but I can't seem to dent the horizontal alignment.

Here's the text box piece:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Name="textLongUrl" TextWrapping="Wrap" InputScope="Url" Height="150" MaxLength="250" 
                      DisplayedMaxLength="250" LengthIndicatorVisible="True" FontSize="20" 
                      Hint="Type or paste URL" HintStyle="{StaticResource HintCustomStyle}" 
                      ActionIcon="Assets\Images\icon-button-32.png"
                      ActionIconTapped="textLongUrl_ActionIconTapped" KeyDown="textLongUrl_KeyDown"  />
```

And  here's the hint style I'm using:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="HintCustomStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the project in blend and Right click on the PhoneTextBox and select Edit Style > Edit a copy to edit the template. Find the Border named "HintBorder" and expand it to see "HintContent" and "ContentElement" ContentControls. "HintBorder" is the one you want.
Select it and from the property panel set the HorizontalAlignment to Center and VerticalAlignment to Center,  that should do it. Your Hint Text is centered.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneTextBoxHintCenterStyle" TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TextBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="HorizontalAlignment" Storyboard.TargetName="Text">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <HorizontalAlignment>Stretch</HorizontalAlignment>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="HintBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LengthIndicatorStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 0, 0, 27"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="32" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LengthIndicatorHidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase Exponent="6"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="LengthIndicator">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.350">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="LengthIndicatorBorder">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LengthIndicator" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="HintBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HintContent" Background="Transparent" Content="{TemplateBinding Hint}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,3,0" Style="{TemplateBinding HintStyle}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ActualHintVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="TextBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="Text" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ActionIconBorder" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="84">
                            <Image x:Name="ActionIcon" Height="26" Source="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}" Width="26"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementTextBlock" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: to my knowledge this is the easiest way. Doing this will create a new style for the PhoneTextBox if you want i can paste in the XAML code for this that was generated from the Blend Designer.

Comment: Would appreciate it very much - every time I open my XAMLs in Blend, it changes everything (like `name=` to `x:name=`), not to mention screwing up indentation :)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the toolkit is already using a predefined template.  The use of Blend allows you to override the "canned" template.  The solution worked great for me.

[See this tutorial](http://fetchmytip.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-center-hint-in-wp8-toolkit.html)